# (C++) How to tell when every value after the first in a string is uppercase or lowercase

Tags: c++, string

I need to take any string like 'Lollipop' and the code needs to see if every single value after the first letter is uppercase or not. If every value is uppercase, I need it to increase an outside variable by 1. I am not sure how to do this as the length of the string can vary. The inputted word has a constraint of 2-10 characters and the first letter must start with a capital letter. I did this by simply doing stringName(0) == Ascii range for uppercase. I just have no clue how to check the rest of the string to see if it is entirely lowercase or not. The code can only use iostream and string.
Thanks

Comment: Hint: start with a pice of paper and a pencil

Comment: Well I know how to actually do it with for loops, I just don’t know how to increase the outside variable by 1 when it’s true for every character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the answer of @Gokul, which is not complete correct:

```
bool checkForAllUppercase(std::string str) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
        if (isupper(str[i])) 
          counter++;
        else 
          return false; // you can leave the for-loop if you find the first not upper-case letter
    }
    if (counter == str.size())  // check if all values where upper case
        return true;
    else 
          return false;
    return false;
}

int main() {
    ...
    if(checkForAllUppercase(exastr))
        variable++;
}
```

I wrote a function which returns true, if all letters are upper-case and false if not. Example usage is shown also

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::isupper()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) and [`std::all_of()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) to make the code more compact:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

bool isStrUpperCase(const std::string& str) {
    const auto start = std::next(str.begin());
    // skip first character, you'll have to make sure
    // your string has at least two characters!
    return std::all_of(start, str.end(),
        [](const char c){ return std::isupper(c) != 0; });
}
```

Comment: Passing a `std::string_view` by value instead of a `std::string` by constant reference is recommended, btw.